# Why does $A_6$ 6-cycle from $S_6$ which also has even number of 2-cycles and hence is even permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

For $S_6$,the possible orders are 1,2,3,4,5,6.

While for $A_6$, the possible orders are 1,2,3,4,5 but not 6.

Why does $A_6$ neglects the 6-cycle in $S_n$
which also has 0 number of 2-cycles and hence an even permutation .

I was going to upload the image of possible orders of $S_6$. but error pops up that I can't upload it .

Comment: You are confusing the order of a permutation with the sign of the permutation, which is given by:  those that can only be expressed with an odd number of transpositions, and those that can only be expressed with an odd number of transpositions.  $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) \in S_6$ is odd.  $(1,2,3,4,5) \in S_6$ is even, hence in $A_6$.  Please review your notes on transpositions (or permutations written in 2-cycles that are not necessarily disjoint).

Comment: @amWhy  pardon me sir if I am missing something again ,but I want to ask that $1,2,3,4,5,6$ is a 6-cycle and has no 2-cycle in it . $A_6$ will contain every possible arrangement such that number of 2-cycles is even. 6-cycle has even no of 2-cycle thus it must be in $A_6$. I am distributing possible arrangement in $S_6$as 6-cycle,5-cycle and one fixed point, 4-cycle and 2fixed points ,4-cycle and one transposition (2-cycle) etc. $1,2,3,4,5$has form of a 5-cycle and fixed point thus even no. of 2-cycle and belongs to $A_6 $.

Comment: In terms of a single cycle, order of the permutation is its length.  But the number of numbers in the single cycle does not determine even or odd-ness. Every permutation (including single-cycles), can be expressed in terms of an even or an odd number of transpositions.  For example, in the question I link to, there are at least two algorithms (or ways) in which to express, e.g. (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) as a product of (usually not disjoint) transpositions:  (12)(23)(34)(45)(56).  Count the transpositions: there are five, hence the six cycle we started with is odd, and hence, not an element in $A_6$.

Comment: The same odd number of transpositions results if we use a similar, but different way of decomposing the 6-cycle into transpositions: $(123456) = (16)(15)(14)(13)(12)$. Again, we have an odd number of transpositions. An transposition that is decomposed into an odd number of transpositions, can never be decomposed in any way, to an even number of transpositions.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks sir ,I just remembered that only a cycle(single)with odd length can generate Even Number of 2-cycle .(1,2,3,4,5,6) is of order even and hence cannot . Thanks sir .

Comment: Glad to have helped.